# Perforce (2013.3) changelist not showing checked out files

Tags: perforce

I have no filters applied, yet every file I check out won't appear in any changelist for any length of time. I will click on the dropdown arrow to see the files in the changelist, they will briefly appear then disappear. I've looked around in different places for a setting that might be wrong, but I don't see anything....any ideas?

Comment: Is the command line reporting everything correctly?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor - I did: p4 changes -s pending -c [client] ... it lists the changelist I created. I've moved some of the files to this changelist in GUI by right-click->Move to Another Changelist. I then do: p4 opened -c 30515 and it shows the files. So, it seems correct to me in that regard, but p4 opened -c default gives "files not opened on this client"...and yeah, there are still other files checked out to the default changelist.

Comment: No ideas on this one anybody? Maybe it's a question for the perforce creators...

Comment: Might be a question for P4 support at this point, it's possible that something got screwed up in the metadata?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm inclined to think. Thanks for taking the time.